# How to fix 'PCH Warning: header stop not at file scope'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers

I've set up my programs and header files as what I think is the correct way, but I keep getting the error mentioned in the title.

I have tried searching for fixes for this issue, which most of them were simply adding ';' after the class definition in a header file. I've tried most all the fixes I could find with the same results.

Here is the main program where the error is flagging:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include "computeGross.h"
#include "computeInsurance.h"
#include "Employee.h" /*<-----------------This is where the error flags*/
using namespace std;

int main()
{ }
```

And here is the header file that the error is flagging:

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Employee
{
    string name;
    double rate;
    double hours;
    double insurance;
    double social;
    double stateTax;
    double fedTax;
    double netPay;
    double grossPay;
};

#endif
```

Comment: I assume you are on some version of Visual Studio. Never include `pch.h` in a header. Always put `#include "pch.h"` as the first line of every one of your .cpp files

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but never use `using namespace std;` in a header file. Because what if the user of your header *has conflicting definitions*!?

Comment: Also your error could be in one of your "compute" headers and you only see the error message in employee because it is the last one.

Comment: Other than the error message I don't see any usage of precompiled headers in the presented files.

Comment: @drescherjm It might be in the Makefile or whatever he is using. I've seen some for GCC / clang which use `-include pch.hpp` and have rules to automatically collect header file dependencies into `pch.hpp`

Comment: @drescherjm I am using VS Community 2019, and have added the VS tag.

Comment: My guess is that `computeGross.h` or `computeInsurance.h` improperly includes `pch.h`

Comment: `using namespace std;` in a header is not illegal but a very bad practice. However I don't see anything at all wrong with the code that is in the question.

Comment: Your endif in your real file does not have those backticks on it, does it? It should not.

Comment: @ZanLynx no, that was a mistake while formatting my question.

Comment: @drescherjm I have not included pch.h anywhere in my files, also, I'm only using namespace std due to errors thrown when I tried 'std::string' in my 'Employee' class.

Comment: So precompiled headers are not enabled in your project at all?

Comment: To form a code block in the editor copy the text. Select it and press the {} button. I fixed the code blocks.

Comment: @drescherjm no, the only headers in use are the ones included in my main.

Comment: I expect that this may then be a weird false positive from the `Intellisense`. It does not always get its suggestions correct.

Answer (score 17):

FYI, I encountered this when I left a ; off of a declaration in another .h file. Since that declaration was never finished, when the #define was encountered in the next .h file it threw this error.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the order of your header files. Try making a new cpp file and include the headers one at a time. See which one breaks.

Reduce the possible causes of the error until you find it.

Comment: I made a new cpp and there were no issues until I added the 'Employee' header.

Comment: @Stanky-kun Keep reducing it. Make the Employee struct empty. Remove the ifndef,define,endif bits. Etc.

Comment: I included Employee first before my other headers and the problem resolved. I assume since the other headers were also including employee, it needed to be included first in my main. Thanks.